# Shopify: How to remove/replace default card logos either from the code or admin settings?

Tags: frontend, shopify, liquid

The part of the page which displays the card logo is from the the following HTML. When searching through the project folder, I don't find this anywhere. I tried to look this up in the Edit Code section of the Shopify admin, but didn't find. All I need to do is replace the default logos with a single custom logo that I have. The image following the code shows that I part I am looking for the code for.

```
<div id="trust-badge-content-div" class="trust-badge-preview trust-badge-product" data-trustbadge-specificity="1" data-hc-insertion-order="0" style="box-sizing: border-box; text-align: center; width: 100%; margin: 15px 0px;"><div class="tb-text-div" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px;"><div class="tb-text" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center;">Secure checkout with major credit cards including these and more.</div><div class="tb-badge-div"><div class="tb-badge" style="width: 65px; display: inline-block; margin: 0px 7px; vertical-align: top;"><img class="tb-svg" src="https://hektorcommerce.com/apps/trustbadge/svg_images/?image=122-american-express" alt="American Express" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div><div class="tb-badge" style="width: 65px; display: inline-block; margin: 0px 7px; vertical-align: top;"><img class="tb-svg" src="https://hektorcommerce.com/apps/trustbadge/svg_images/?image=120-discover" alt="Discover" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div><div class="tb-badge" style="width: 65px; display: inline-block; margin: 0px 7px; vertical-align: top;"><img class="tb-svg" src="https://hektorcommerce.com/apps/trustbadge/svg_images/?image=129-visa" alt="Visa" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div><div class="tb-badge" style="width: 65px; display: inline-block; margin: 0px 7px; vertical-align: top;"><img class="tb-svg" src="https://hektorcommerce.com/apps/trustbadge/svg_images/?image=108-master-card-1" alt="MasterCard" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div></div></div></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please include wich theme you use, this can be on multiple places

Comment: Prestige theme.

Comment: go to online store  / customize, select footer, click on the word footer to see the section options, uncheck "Show payment methods"

Comment: But, it looks like these icons aren't part of the footer since they appear right below the product tabs. The ones that appear at the bottom were removed a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

To better help you, please share the name of the theme you use.

In general, the option to show or hide cards is on the footer or on the theme settings.  Go to theme / customize and search for the option to hide credit cards in these two places.

UPDATE: on theme prestige the option is on footer.

after find the option on customize (footer section) go to edit code

sections/footer  (around line 156 depending your previous customizetions) you'll find this:

```js
 {%- if section.settings.show_payment_methods -%}
   <!-- change the content of this if -->
    {%- capture payment_methods -%}
      {%- for type in shop.enabled_payment_types -%}
        <li class="HorizontalList__Item">{{ type | payment_type_svg_tag }}</li>
      {%- endfor -%}
    {%- endcapture -%}

    {%- if payment_methods != blank -%}
      <ul class="Footer__PaymentList HorizontalList">
        {{ payment_methods }}
      </ul>
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endif -%}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the efforts. I found this code. I just commented this entire code out to see if the icons are hidden. But they still appear. I even tried clearing browser cache.

Comment: Besides, I don't see an option in theme settings to remove these payment icons

Comment: This is the page I want these icons removed from. https://reflectperfection.com/collections/vanity-mirrors/products/10x1x-reversible-large-column-stem-vanity-makeup-mirror

Comment: you have an app Trustbage by hektorcommerce than inject this on your page, verify the apps you have installed on your page

Comment: Thanks. Yes, we got Trustbadge app. Please explain what I need to do with the app. Is there any connection between this app and the code in your answer?

Comment: Any more ideas, chefjuanpi?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see this app in our store from where these trusted badges come.

Comment: if you don't like the trust badge for the app you can remove the app, and just update the code on the footer to show your own images

Comment: Actually, app got an option to let you hide or show and I took advantage of it without having to remove the app.

Comment: If you don't use an app is not a good idea keep it because even hided it continue to charge on your sita and affect speed. you have other apps installed giving similar functions, just delete the app is the clean solution

Comment: Yes, my client also say what you said when I asked if there was any more use of this app.